# How to properly insulate a room

Tags: insulation

I am converting a small room in my house with 2 interior walls and 2 exterior walls into a sauna.

It is of paramount importance that no heat leaks through the interior walls into the adjoining rooms.  I am willing to go space-age on this one.  What is the foolproof, no-mistakes way of making sure 100% of the heat in one room stays in that one room?  For bonus points what is the proper way to control for humidity issues here?

Comment: 1. What is the source of heat that is only inside that room?  2. If it is so hot that leakage into other rooms would be a problem, how hot will it be?  3. Will the heat be continuous or for brief periods?  4. If it is a small room, it will get a lot smaller.  The only way to prevent any heat from migrating to adjacent rooms is to contain it within a shell surrounded by air conditioned space, with the heat transferred out of that space.  5.  If you are also worried about humidity, you will need to provide more information about the nature of the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  The question posted asks for something other than Home Improvement - it is Click bait.

Comment: hey @fixer1234 if the mods here weren't so damn helpful you would see that i am converting a room into a sauna with 2 interior walls and 2 exterior.  hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, but you're not going to like it.  You have to build spaces within the walls that are reverse pressure vessels (designed for the pressure to be on the *outside*, e.g. like a submarine).  Then draw a vacuum on those spaces. Vacuum is a superb insulator.  So yes, indeed your solution will be "space" age.

The problem is that somewhere this vessel must have edges, and/or "reverse staybolts" to keep the space from being crushed.  Those conduct heat.  Since the reverse staybolts will be in compression, maybe  you could make them out of a stack of Peltier devices and force them to pump heat in the direction you want.  But then once you're pumping heat, you might as well just use common freon heat pumps and just outpump the thermal losses through cheap common-as-dirt fiberglass insulation.

Comment: thanks @Harper.  even though they changed the title of my question i think you got at what i was asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely, positively, no practical way to ensure that:

> "no heat leaks through the interior walls into the adjoining rooms"

Even with "space-age" technology. If spacecraft did not have thermal control/management systems, the astronauts (and equipment) would suffer wild unsurvivable temperature swings due to radiated heat from the sun being conducted through the walls/body of the craft.